# Given an array of integers A and an integer m, determine the maximum product of m consecutive integers in the array

Tags: java, arrays, big-o

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Part1 {
    public static int maxProduct(Array[] a, int m) {
    int maxProduct = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    if (a.length < m) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - m; i++) {
        int product = 1;
        for (int j = i; j < m + i; j++) {
            product = product * Arrays.asList(a).indexOf(j);
        }
        maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, product);
    }
    return maxProduct;  
}
```

}
I am trying to find the max product of m consecutive integers in an array and I believe I have come up with a viable solution. However, I need my solution to have a worse-case runtime of O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve the problem that the array contains 0：

```
.
.
.
int product = 1;
int maxProduct = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
if ( m < 1) return 0;
for(int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if (a[i] == 0) a[i] = 1; // solution
    if (i < m) {
        product *= a[i];
        maxProduct = product;
    } else {
        product = product * a[i] / a[i - m];
        maxProduct = maxProduct > product ? maxProduct : product;
    }
}
return maxProduct;
```

But the array is a reference type, which will change the original array, so is there a better way? yes! we have :

```
.
.
.
int product = 1;
int maxProduct = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
if ( m < 1) return 0;
for(int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    int spi = a[i] == 0 ? 1 : a[i];
    if (spi == 0) spi = 1;
    if (i < m) {
        product *= spi;
        maxProduct = product;
    } else {
        int spi_m = a[i - m] == 0 ? 1 : a[i - m];
        product = product * spi / spi_m;
        maxProduct = maxProduct > product ? maxProduct : product;
    }
}
return maxProduct;
```

---

Here is the original answer：

```
.
.
.
int product = 1;
int maxProduct = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
if ( m < 1) return 0;
for(int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if (i < m) {
        product *= a[i];
        maxProduct = product;
    } else {
        product = product * a[i] / a[i - m];
        maxProduct = maxProduct > product ? maxProduct : product;
    }
}
return maxProduct;
```

an array like this:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,8,9

if m is 3

so, in for loop:

1. when i = 0, i = 1, i = 2   (i < 3 )
   product *= a[i] =>
   product = 1 * 1, product = 1 * 2 (now product is 2), product = 2 * 3 = 1 * 2 * 3 (m consecutive integers in the array)

maxProduct = 1,  maxProduct = 2,  maxProduct = 6

then i = 3,4,5,6,7,10,8,9 (i >= 3)
if i is 3
product = product * a[i] / a[i - m]  = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 / 1 = 2 * 3 * 4(m consecutive integers in the array)

product > maxProduct

so the maxProduct now is product

if i is 4
product = product * a[i] / a[i - m]  = 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 / 2 = 3 * 4 * 5(m consecutive integers in the array)

product > maxProduct

so the maxProduct now is product

but when i > 8

product < maxProduct

maxProduct will still maxProduct not change

!!! english is hard!

Comment: sorry what do you initialize product as

Comment: @Jerome type int, value 1;According to your needs, you can modify some details yourself, I just implemented the function, the details are not considered

Comment: Are you using an int[] for a because I get an error for a.length

Comment: @Jerome, yes i use int[] a = {....} to test this!

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: I don't believe this solution works if the array contains 0s

Comment: @Jerome After a little thought, yes, including zeros doesn't seem like a good idea, it looks like we need to look for other solutions

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no O(n+m).  Since m <= n by definition, O(n+m) <= O(n+n) <= O(2n) and O(2n) is O(n).  Secondly-  the trick is that you don't need to loop to calculate the product every time.  If for index (i, i+1, ... i+m-1) the product is p, then the product for (i+1, i+2..., i+m) is `p/a[i]*a[i+m]`.  So you can calculate the new product by math rather than a second inner loop.

```
int product = initial_product(a,m); //gets the initial product
for(int i=m; i < a.length(); i++) {
    product = product * a[i]/a[i-m-1]
    //Check value of product here
}
```

Comment: I believe this solution would give you an infinite loop

Comment: @Jerome No it wouldn't.  There's only 1 loop, which has a fixed length-  from m to the length of a increasing by 1 each time.  An infinite loop isn't a possibility there.

Comment: Okay because I did try implementing this and it gave me an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a rolling product of `m` elements to find the max product in one pass.

Pseudo code:

1. multiply the first `m` numbers, saving as `max` and `current`
2. iterate over the remaining elements:

   1. set `current` to `current` divided by element `i-m`
   2. set `current` to `current` multiplied by element `i`
   3. set `max` to `max(max, current)`

This is a single pass over the array, so it's O(n).

In code:

```java
public static int maxProduct(int[] a, int m) {
    int maxProduct = Integer.MIN_VALUE, current = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i < m) {
            current *= a[i];
        } else {
            current = current / a[i - m] * a[i]; // see note below
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, current);
        }
    }
    return maxProduct;
}
```

Integer division is safe (won't result in non-integer) because `current` has `a[i-m]` as a factor, `current` having been built from it.

Answer (score 0):

An [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html#sum--) version

```
public static int maxProduct(int[] a, int m) {
    if (m <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    m = Math.max(m, a.length);
    int product = IntStream.of(a).limit(m).sum();

   
    int maxProduct = product;
    for (int i = m; i < a.length; i++) {
        product /= a[i - m];
        product *= a[i];
        maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, product);
    }
    return maxProduct;
    
    /* MY BUG
    return IntStream.range(m, a.length)
        .iterate(product, i-> (pr -> (pr / a[i - m]) * a[i]))
        .max().orElse(0);
    */
}
```

A bit of APL feeling.

The time complexity is O(N). It is using a *running* product, deleting the contribution of the oldest factor and adding the new factor: 2 operations, O(1). Repeated *N - m* times, hence O(N).